# SPF record issue

Tags: dns, spf

sometimes, erratically, when my server sends an email to an "internal" address managed by google apps as a distribution list I get those errors

```
Received: from ovhprod.diveboard.com ([2607:5300:60:1d85::1])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e4si6519596qas.128.2013.08.14.00.28.57
    for <logs@diveboard.com>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
    Wed, 14 Aug 2013 00:28:57 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning plugin@diveboard.com does not designate 2607:5300:60:1d85::1 as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:5300:60:1d85::1;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning plugin@diveboard.com does not designate 2607:5300:60:1d85::1 as permitted sender)
```

I did add SPF records but it looks like I did it wrong - any hint !?

```
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 a mx include:smtp1.uservoice.com ~all"
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all"
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 ip4:192.95.11.34/30 ptr ?all"
@ 10800 IN SPF "v=spf1 ip4:198.27.68.133/32 ip6:2607:5300:60:1d85::1/64 ptr ?all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:smtp1.uservoice.com ~all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:192.95.11.34/30 ptr ?all"
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:198.27.68.133/32 ip6:2607:5300:60:1d85::1/64 ptr ?all"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one 1 SPF string per host. A SPF record can be specified as TXT or SPF record. The best practice is to have 1 TXT and 1 SPF record.

Check your domain here:
http://spf.myisp.ch

I suggest you read the whole SPF page on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#FAIL_and_forwarding

Answer (score 0):

Your SPF record is not well written. You can have only one SPF record.

You could replace all of them with

```
"v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:192.95.11.34/30 ip4:198.27.68.133/32 ip6:2607:5300:60:1d85::1/64 include:smtp1.uservoice.com  include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all"
```

However the last SPF specification recommends avoiding PTR mechanism.